# How display the cities array info?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, json, gtl

```
Set @record_search = '{"age":42,"cities":["Cobbtown, GA","Metter, GA"]}'

{{.datasource JSONVar type=variable source=@json maxRows = 20}}
{{.data}}
{ "target" : "@record_search" }
{{/data}}

%%[ for @alias = 1 to JSONVar.aliases do]%%
{{alias}}
%%[ next @j ]%%

{{/datasource}}
```

Comment: Please add context, explanation and reasons why your code does not work. Code only questions usually do not get a good response here

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you have the option of modifying your data source's structure or not (e.g., converting your `cities` array from a collection of strings to a collection of objects), but if you do, you can iterate through a nested collection of objects using a nested `datasource` tag whose type is set to `nested`:

```
%%[
Var @record_search
Set @record_search = '{"age":42,"cities":[{city:"Cobbtown, GA"}, {city:"Metter, GA"}]}'
]%%
{{.datasource Records type=variable}}
  {{.data}}
    {"target": "@record_search"}
  {{/data}}
  Age:<br>
  {{age}}<br>
  <br>
  Cities:<br> 
  {{.datasource Cities type=nested}}
    {{.data}}
      {"target": "Records.cities" }
    {{/data}}
    {{Cities.city}}<br>
  {{/datasource}}
{{/datasource}}
```

Output:

```
Age:
42

Cities:
Cobbtown, GA
Metter, GA
```